# Does the Thorncaster Sliver's ability damage have to be assigned before or after blockers are declared?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have 5 slivers and one of them is a Thorncaster, will I need to assign the "1 damage to target creature or player" before or after my opponent declares blockers?

My guess is that it is as I attack, but I would like it to be after blockers are assigned.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate or can be gleaned from the other questions that have been asked/answered recently relating to Thorncaster Sliver.

Comment: @ColinD - You are right.  I should have looked at that question.  (Funny that we both used the same example of 5 slivers attacking.)

Comment: As a side note, you often wouldn't want it to be after blockers are assigned. Since it is before blockers are assigned, you can use the damage to remove potential blockers

Comment: I voted to reopen it. I explain why [here](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1070/2474).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with most abilities, you choose the targets as part of placing the ability on the stack. The damage is assigned and resolves before any blockers are declared.

I will cite ikegami's answer from another question related to Thorncaster Sliver.

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/12644/3128

> Here's what happens:
>
> 1. You attack with five slivers. Five instances of Thorncaster Sliver's ability triggers
> 2. **You place the abilities on the stack in the order of your choice**: (Best order used)
>
>    1. You place PS#1's ability on the stack targeting the 2/2
>    2. You place PS#2's ability on the stack targeting the 2/2
>    3. You place TS's ability on the stack targeting the Blood Artist
>    4. You place MS#1's ability on the stack targeting your opponent
>    5. You place MS#2's ability on the stack targeting your opponent
> 3. **MS#2's ability resolves:**
>
>    1. Deal one damage to your opponent.
> 4. **MS#1's ability resolves**:
>
>    1. Deal one damage to your opponent.
> 5. **TS's ability resolves**:
>
>    1. Deal one damage to the Blood Artist
> 6. The Blood Artist dies. Blood Artist's ability triggers.
> 7. Your opponent places Blood Artist's ability on the stack targeting you.
> 8. Blood Artist's ability resolves:
>
>    1. You lose one life.
>    2. Your opponent gains one life.
> 9. PS#2's ability resolves:
>
>    1. Deal one damage to the 2/2.
> 10. PS#2's ability resolves:
>
>     1. Deal one damage to the 2/2.
> 11. The 2/2 dies.
> 12. **[Move on the Declare Blockers]**

The emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 3):

Before blockers are declared.

---

First of all, it's not combat damage, so it's not assigned. The ability *triggers*, the ability is *placed on the stack*, targets are *chosen*, the ability *resolves*, and the Sliver *deals damage*.

The ability triggers when the Sliver attacks, which means when it's declared as an attacker.

The ability gets placed on the stack the next time a player would get priority [CR 112.3c], which is still within the Declare Attackers step. That means the ability resolves and causes damage to be dealt in that step too.

My [earlier answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/12644/3128) covers a very similar scenario in detail.