# When does Thorncaster Sliver's ability resolve?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When you attack with [Thorncaster Sliver](http://magiccards.info/m14/en/158.html) and the ability triggers, does it do the damage from the attack first or the ability first?

Comment: This is answered by [Do Thorncaster Sliver's triggered abilities go on the stack?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12641/do-thorncaster-slivers-triggered-abilities-go-on-the-stack) and then by [Does the Thorncaster Sliver's ability damage have to be assigned before or after blockers are declared?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12656/does-the-thorncaster-slivers-ability-damage-have-to-be-assigned-before-or-after). This is the third time this has been asked this week!

Answer (score 2):

Ability, before blockers are even declared.

---

The ability triggers when the Sliver attacks, which means when it's declared as an attacker.

The ability gets placed on the stack the next time a player would get priority [CR 112.3c], which is still within the Declare Attackers step. That means the ability resolves and causes damage to be dealt in that step too.

My [earlier answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/12644/3128) covers a very similar scenario in detail.